# php call python without exec permission

Tags: php

My assigment requires me to run a python file through webpage. I tried calling this php page through ajax

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' )
{
   exec("rm index.*");
   print exec("wget -O index.html http:    markets.usatoday.com/custom/usatoday-com/html-mktscreener.asp");
   print exec("python hw7-9.py index.html");
   print "Done!";
}
else
{
   print "Nice try!"; //someone is trying to manually run
}
```

However I just realized that I don't have exec function permissions (after trying echo exec('whoami'). I chmod the file to 777.

I need to someone run the python script through some sort of ajax call. I am running on an afs system with SunOS.

Comment: Just a note, spoofing the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header is trivial.

Comment: @pna the main index page has to be but I can call any other format file

Answer (score 0):

Without permission to run "exec" your options are very limited.

If your web server is set up to support python scripts via cgi you could use an htnml redirect to the python script.

`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/hw7.9.py">`